# Chrome extension to reload and close tab after a time interval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am working on a extension for google chrome that reloads the a tab once after 2 seconds that the page has loaded and after that waits for 30 minutes and closes the tab or google chrome window.
ive tried these scripts in my 1.js file but none of them seem to worked

```
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function() {document.documentElement.style.display = '';}, 1000);
    chrome.tabs.reload()
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function() {document.documentElement.style.display = '';}, 1000);
    chrome.tabs.remove()
```

an heres my manfest file:

```
    {"name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "content_scripts": 
    [{"matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["1.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "permissions": 
    ["tabs", "http://*/*"]}]}
```

her's what it says in the java console:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined
```

thank you all

Comment: You have a very strange manifest.json format going on there, I would suggest you re-do that and see if it fixes your problem. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

Comment: I'm not sure what causing the issue. According to [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) `content scripts` doesn't have the property `permissions`.

Comment: i just updated the new manifest and 1.js but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're invoking the chrome.tabs.* methods properly? Provide a snippet please.

Comment: So copying right from the chrome API reference: `chrome.tabs.remove(integer or array of integer tabIds, function callback)`. The callback function is optional, the tabId is not.

You need to provide the tabId for your chrome.tabs.remove method. You can grab the tabId with chrome.tabs.getCurrent

Comment: please help me i have been dealing with this issue for a month now

Comment: I already answered you! Your chrome.tabs.remove invocation is wrong. Try `chrome.tabs.remove(tabID)`.

Are you sure you have a tab open other than the new tab. The chrome.tabs.reload method is giving you an undefined error which means it cannot find a selected tab of the current window. Check here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-reload

Try giving it the optional parameter of tabID into the chrome.tabs.reload method.